# pandas read_fwf special character not loading correctly

Tags: python, pandas

so i have the following data in test.txt:

```
étoufee
placing
```

and the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

widths = [4,3]
names = ["part1", "part2"]

df = pd.read_fwf('test.txt',widths = widths, names = names, encoding = 'utf8')
print df
```

and the output is:

```
  part1 part2
0   éto   ufe
1  plac   ing
```

notice the first line. the special character is causing read_fwf to read the length correctly, and we're losing data. I've tried setting encoding = utf-8 but that didn't work. Any other options?

---

for those who might look at this in the future, here's the updated code

```
# encoding=utf8

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
import sys, locale
import codecs


with codecs.open('test.txt','r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()



widths = [4,3]
names = ["part1", "part2"]

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(text),widths = widths, names = names, encoding = 'utf8')
print(df)
```

Comment: `import sys` and check `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` and `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. You can take it from there by making the appropriate changes. You can also try `locale`: `import locale; locale.getlocale(); locale.setlocale('YOUR_LANGUAGE', 'UTF8')`.

Comment: Doesn't you file have a BOM before étouffee ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***NOT AN ANSWER***
just possibly helpful

```
txt = """étoufee
placing"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

widths = [4,3]
names = ["part1", "part2"]

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(txt),widths = widths, names = names, encoding = 'utf8')
print(df)

  part1 part2
0  étou   fee
1  plac   ing
```

---

```
import sys, locale
print(sys.version)
print(pd.__version__)
print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
print(locale.getlocale())

3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)]
0.19.0
utf-8
utf-8
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
```